# Why django template if statement works wrong?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using Django 3.1.0 and i have problem with the below if statement.

```
{% if group == "TEACHER" %}
        {% include "staticPages/components/teacher_dash.html" %}
{% else %}
        {% include "staticPages/components/student_dash.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

```
#views.py
def dashboard_page(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        group = request.user.groups.objects.first().name
        context = {
            'group':group,
        }
        return render(request, 'staticPages/dashboard.html', context)
    else:
        return redirect('/404/')
```

the `group` variable stored the name of `user.Groups.objects.first().name` as string.

While the group variable is equal to `TEACHER` it runs the forth line instead of the second line.

I have tried printing out the `group` variable and copying it to the if condition but it did not worked.

Every answer would be appreciated.

Comment: `group` is likely not a string, but a `Group` object? Can you share what `group` exactly is (as well as its model)?

Comment: I added what is stored in group to the question text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks of every one i did solved it by adding the `stringformat` to my template.